# Foreign package in R

Tags: r, package, installation

I am fairly new to R and having some issues installing the foreign package. I get the following message:

```
package ‘foreign’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

from the following line of code:

```
install.packages('foreign')
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: This package was recently updated after R went live with R version 4.0. I suggest trying to update your R version to 4.0 and see if it works.

Answer (score 8):

You could update to R version 4. For R version 3, there are several options using version 0.8-76. You could install from source:

```
 install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/foreign/foreign_0.8-76.tar.gz")
```

Alternatively, you could use an old binary. For Windows:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/foreign_0.8-76.zip")
```

And for Mac:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/foreign_0.8-76.tgz")
```

Answer (score -3):

You can click on **Tools** then **Install Packages..** write foreign then click Install.